# numpy if A > Value, change B to constant

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

**Problem:**

I've got a function with two arrays, but if the input data and result are within certain limits, the returned value is a constant:

```
def funcB(A, C1, C2):
    B = (0.381*A) + (0.05*(C1/C2)) - 0.15
    B[B > 1.0] = 1.0
    B[B < 0.5] = 0.5
    return B
```

In the above B is the result, if it is > 1.0 then it is 1, and < 0.5 is 0.5.

What I am struggling to do is also add a condition where if the input A is < 1.64 result B is also 0.5, and where if it is > 3.3 result B is 1.0

Comment: You can use `numpy.where` to find indices where `A` satisfies some conditions. Since `A` and `B` has the same shape, using those indices (mask) you can set `B`'s value.

Comment: You can do the same as you did above. `B[A < 1.64] = 0.5`, assuming A is the same shape as B and there are no broadcasting shenanigans.

Comment: @Reti43 from the way `B` is defined, it is clear that `A` can broadcast to `B`, so this should work fine.

Comment: @SvenMarnach If `C1` and `C2` are constants, sure. But the following doesn't work. `A = np.ones((5,)); C1 = C2 = np.ones((3, 1)); B = A + C1 / C2; B[A < 0.5]`

Answer (score 0):

Reti43 - that worked!

Solution was as simple as:

```
def FuncB(A, C1, C2):
B = ((0.381*A) + (0.05*(C1/C2)) - 0.15).reshape(A.shape)
B[B > 1.0] = 1.0
B[B < 0.5] = 0.5
B[A < 1.64] = 0.5
B[A > 3.3] = 1.0
return B
```

Comment: You can also combine the boolean arrays with bitwise or. B[(B > 1.) | (A > 3.3)] = 1. By the way, without knowing what values C1 and C2 take, it is possible for an element of B to be less than .5, but the respective in A to be more than 3.3. In that case you'd have competing conditions about which value it should finally take.

Comment: That's going to be really useful for other stuff though, so thanks!